# Creating new AngularJS component with Yeoman generator-ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, web, ionic-framework

After generating a new ionic app using Yeoman [generator-ionic](https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic), I can't create a new AngularJS component (controller / route / directive etc').

I've tried `yo generator-ionic:controller myController` with no luck. Couldn't find anything in the docs too. what is the right way scaffolding new component?

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost a year old. That said, someone else might find it and want an answer.

First, your syntax is wrong. When doing a `yo xxxx` you leave off the `generator-`. Second, the ionic generator doesn't have a sub-generator for making a controller. You can use the angular generator as a complement. If you don't have it, run `npm install generator-angular -g` and then you can do a `yo angular:controller test`. When I did that, it seemed to understand my main module just fine, but it put the controller in scripts/controller/test.js.

The angular sub-generators available are:

- common
- constant
- controller
- decorator
- directive
- factory
- filter
- main
- provider
- route
- service
- value
- view